# Intersection over union understanding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

Was reading some code online for IOU implementation in python and most of the part I understood very much but there is some confusion regarding core maths of it.

Here is the code:

```
def get_iou(boxA, boxB):
    # This will calculate boxes given in any order...
    # This will get max value between 2 boxes becuase max mening overlapping 
    # area just begins for x 
    interxA = max(boxA[0], boxB[0])
    # This will get max value between 2 boxes becuase max mening overlapping 
    # area just begins for y
    interyA = max(boxA[1], boxB[1])
    # This will get min value between 2 boxes becuase min mening overlapping 
    # area just begins for x because bottom right should be less as it's ending
    interxB = min(boxA[2], boxB[2])
    # This will get min value between 2 boxes becuase min mening overlapping 
    # area just begins for y because bottom right should be less as it's ending
    interyB = min(boxA[3], boxB[3])

    # Now basic concept to find area of any rectangle in co-ordinate plane we 
    # can think in this way, this is values top-left: (xa, ya), 
    # bottom-right: (xb, yb)
    # (xb - xa + 1) * (yb - ya + 1) this formula will yield us the area of that 
    # rectangle


    # this will find area of intersection rectangle
    interArea = max(0, interxB - interxA + 1) * max(0, interyB - interyA + 1)

    boxAarea = (boxA[2] - boxA[0] + 1) * (boxA[3] - boxA[1] + 1)
    boxBarea = (boxB[2] - boxB[0] + 1) * (boxB[3] - boxB[1] + 1)

    return (interArea / (boxAarea + boxBarea - interArea))
```

In the above code why do we use **"+ 1"** as a part of code because I checked with and without for like this one: get_iou([25, 25, 175, 200], [45, 45, 175, 200]) and it changes but only few decimal place ? Does it matters if I use and if some body can even explain why we need it at all that would be more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not looked into this - but it could be like a Laplace smoother to ensure that we are not biasing certain conditions of the box size. I will take a look (or more likely follow this post :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a code tweak to prevent the denominator of the fraction from being 0 in some cases. For example, if we remove the `+1` from the code and both boxes are equal, we get a return 0/0. Mathematically this is interpreted as a 1, but computationally this will be a math error.

Comment: I used this box as equal boxes ([25, 25, 175, 200], [25, 25, 175, 200]) and it gives me 0.9933774834437086.

Comment: I guess this problem would be solved by adding something directly to the denominator before computing division. Here, however every measure is appended with +1